# Opening a file from a controller url in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I need when you click a link on a website to open a pdf file.  When I put a link to the actual file and you click the link it opens the file itself so you can view it. When you create a controller that reads a file id and sends the file and this works as well. The problem is the customer wants the file to directly open (like the link to actual file method), not just automatically download (like the controller method)

Controller Example (Downloads the file) href="https://mywebsite.com/Download/DownloadFile?downloadId=17"
Link Example (Opens the file directly) href="https://mywebsite.com/pdf/mypdf.pdf"

I have tried in multiple browsers and on multiple computers.  The result is always the same.  I have the file content type set as application/pdf.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your controller method generates the document as the response, you can use the [`Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to specify to the browser how to open it. I think what you want would be to have these headers included:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filenname=mypdf.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

This will work in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your routing for static file.

Steps:

1. In RouteConfig.cs enable routing for static files

   ```
   routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
   ```
2. Add a route for your path to RouteConfig.cs

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
     name: "staticFileRoute",
     url: "pdf/{*file}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "DownloadFile" }
   );
   ```
3. In Web.config add following entry

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="MyCustomUrlHandler2" path="pdf/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
4. Add action "DownloadFile" to "Download" controller, like this:

   ```
   public FileResult DownloadFile(string file)
   {
      string path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/pdf/{0}", file));

      if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
      {
         string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
         return File(path, mime);
      }
      else
           throw new ArgumentException("File not found");
   }
   ```